# actionscript Socket and XMLSocket read full data

Tags: sockets, actionscript

as I can see in XMLSocket the data can be readed fully until the end, on the other hand the Socket class read data by parts, so long string will be concatinated by parts, I wonder if is possible to use the Socket class and still read the full data until the end package

```
private function readResponse():void {
    var str:String = readUTFBytes(bytesAvailable);
    response += str;
    trace2(response);
}
private function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace2("socketDataHandler: " + event);
    readResponse();
}
```

so as I've saw in the docs the only data handler is the ProgressEvent, but how to handle the data to get the full string, not by parts?, I don't want to use the XMLSocket, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

XMLSocket reads data in internal buffer, and when terminating null byte is received it parses all of the XML received since the previous zero byte or, if that is the first message received, since the connection was established.
You need to wrap Socket object, read messages to internal buffer and fire event when you need.